# Does Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2 C# library support PKCE for Desktop applications?

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I am working on integrating a C#/.Net Framework desktop application to Google Sheets API. I have registered my application at developers.google.com where I chose type Desktop and I received a clientId and a clientSecret.
On the client side I want to use the OAuth2 Authorization Code flow to obtain an access token on behalf of the user. I am using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4 NuGet package which exposes some abstractions for obtaining the authorization code and access token(eg: GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync) and for using Sheets API(eg: SheetsService) . But it requires both the Client Id and Client Secret in order to obtain the token.

Since this is a Desktop application how safe is to expose the Client Secret on the client side where all the users who installed my app are able to decompile the app and get the credentials? Is there any PKCE approach like for Web SPA where you don't need a client secret to obtain a token?

This a working version of the flow:

```
private static async Task<UserCredential> GetCredential()
{
    var scopes = new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets" };
    var codeReceiver = new LocalServerCodeReceiver();
    Console.WriteLine(codeReceiver.RedirectUri);

    var authorizeAsync = await Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = "some-client-id",
            ClientSecret = "some-client-secret"
        },
        scopes,
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore("Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user2"),
        codeReceiver: codeReceiver
    );
    return authorizeAsync;
}

 var sheetsService = new Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    HttpClientInitializer = await GetCredential(),
    ApplicationName = "my-app-name",
});

var request = sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range);
```

But as you can see it requires ClientSecret to be provided. Without it, I get an error from Google API Authorization endpoint saying the ClientSecret is missing.
My expectation is for ClientSecret not to be required to obtain an access token for Desktop/Installed apps.

Comment: You are using HTTPS where the https headers and body are encrypted. Also OAuth credentials are encrypted so I'm not sure what you mean by "all the users who installed my app are going to see it".  Authentication for Entity is also encrypted and users will not be able to see other users credentials.

Comment: I was referring to the possibility for a user to decompile the app and get the credentials. Sorry for the confusion, I updated the description.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why you think users of your desktop application will see your client credentials.

When you compile your application ensure that you're client id and secret are complied into it.   Don't have it in a clear text settings file.

While it is true that someone could decompile your application and get your client credentials this is a accepted risk.

The only other option would be to configure an endpoint on your own domain which all requests for your desktop applikation would need to go through on startup to get the credentials.   While this would work it leads to other issues being that if your delivery service goes down your application would not work also if the user doesn't have internet it wouldn't work either.

There is really no perfect solution for desktop apps and Google apis unfortunately

To be clear you need a client id and client secret for authorization token flow with desktop applications, there is no authorization flow that didn't require a secret

Comment: Indeed I was referring to the possibility for a user to decompile the app and get the credentials. So if this is the only way their libraries support, does it mean it is recommended to embed the client secret in the client app? https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2 states "The process results in a client ID and, in some cases, a client secret, which you embed in the source code of your application. (In this context, the client secret is obviously not treated as a secret.)". It's a bit strange to expose the client secret. What are the security risks that may arise?

Comment: Yes it is recommended to compile it within the app.    It needs to be compiled the issue is there is no other option so it is considered an acceptable risk that someone could decompile the app.    If you are worried hosting it does work I have done it in the past for a client.    It just requires that the app be online since you are accessing calendar you need to be online anyway.     Remember you can't give out your client as part of an open source project it must be compiled

Comment: @DalmTo - I can use a client/server approach where instead of using the Google.Apis.Auth library I could make the client call https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth to get the authorization code(call which doesn't require client secret) + expose an API on my backend service to  exchange this code for an access token by calling https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token and this time passing in the client secret(which is safe to be stored on the server side). The problem with this approach is that I lose all the nice features provided by the library(auto token refresh, etc).

Comment: I'm at a loss to understand which flow you are flowing that does not require a secret.   Unless you are using the implicit flow for JavaScript in which case you are not getting a refresh token back.  Try and read though some of the RFC's There is a reason for a client secret.  Its not just there to bother you its there as a security measure.   [The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)

Comment: I was referring to OAuth2 PKCE flow where the client secret is not shipped to the client side. You can read more on this here: https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/authorization-code-flow-with-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce

Comment: as far as I know the google .net client library doesn't support PKCE nore dies the authorization server last I checked.   This is google not auth0

Comment: Google supports as well PKCE - https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app. This is usually an alternative to using clientSecret for SPA web apps. What is strange to me in case of native apps( like mine which is an installed app) Google requires both mechanisms(clientSecret + PKCE).

Comment: When I say google i mean [google-api-dotnet-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client)  if you can get that working yourself I would love to see the code, I have been having issues with Maui and android connection to google authorization.